# Connecting to a remote Oracle Database from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle

How do I connect to an Oracle Database that is not hosted on my loacal machine from visual studio. There seem to samy many different ways that I am getting confused. What kind of information would I need about the host machine and the database before I can proceed? Would I use ODBC or something else? Please help me out with this because I have spent weeks trawling the web and its very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ODP.net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) which is Oracle's official middleware for .net applications.

Once installed, you can connect to a server by using one of the various connection mechanisms that Oracle supports: [EZConnect](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT), LDAP, [TNSNames](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora)...

Once you can access the databases, you can use VS's server explorer to access the db objects